# How do you shift a nested object's values to a higher level and then remove the object? - javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have this decoded NBT object (well part of it anyway) that I need to strip of the useless info and clean up a bit. Is there a way to remove the `type` and `value` keys and then shift the data in `value` up to the place where `value` was previously? I have tried using `const newObj = Object.assign({}, obj, obj.criteria);`, I saw it in another stackoverflow question but that won't really work for my use case.

```
{
  id: { type: 'short', value: 261 },
  Count: { type: 'byte', value: 1 },
  tag: {
    type: 'compound',
    value: {
      ench: { type: 'list', value: { type: 'end', value: [] } },
      Unbreakable: { type: 'byte', value: 1 },
      HideFlags: { type: 'int', value: 254 },
    }
  }
}
```

The outcome should look something like this:

```
{
  id: { type: 'short', value: 261 },
  Count: { type: 'byte', value: 1 },
  tag: {
    ench: { type: 'list', value: { type: 'end', value: [] } },
    Unbreakable: { type: 'byte', value: 1 },
    HideFlags: { type: 'int', value: 254 },
  }
}
```

There are these `object: {type: , value: {}}` things everywhere and I'm trying to get rid of them to clean up the object of useless data, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the assignment `data.tag = data.tag.value;` to obtain the expected result :

```js
let data = {
  id: { type: 'short', value: 261 },
  Count: { type: 'byte', value: 1 },
  tag: {
    type: 'compound',
    value: {
      ench: { type: 'list', value: { type: 'end', value: [] } },
      Unbreakable: { type: 'byte', value: 1 },
      HideFlags: { type: 'int', value: 254 },
    }
  }
};

data.tag = data.tag.value;
console.log(data);
```

Comment: You are welcome,  if you mean you have a nested json with tag property inin various places you should check if the values are objects having the `tag` property  inside, so manually writing a parser or checking for a json parser library.